# Dismiss share extension from custom SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

I am using custom SwiftUI view from main target for sharing document from ShareViewController  of share extension. Using Navigation link and sharing the document after navigating through three views. document is uploaded without any problem, but I don't know how to close the views after upload is done.

This is how navigation looks like

ShareViewController(SLComposeServiceViewController) -> PropertyListView  -> UnitListView -> UploadView

and didPost looks like this

```
override func didSelectPost() {
    print("In Did Post")
    if let item = self.extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem{
        print("Item \(item)")
        print(item.attachments)
        print(item.attachments![0])
        let itemProvider = item.attachments![0]
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("com.adobe.pdf"){
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "com.adobe.pdf", options: nil) { (item, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }else{
                    if let url = item as? URL{
                        print(url)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                            //saving to user defaults
                            let dict: [String : Any] = ["dcument" :  url.absoluteString, "name" : self.contentText.isEmpty ? url.lastPathComponent : self.contentText!]
                            let savedata =  UserDefaults.init(suiteName:"group.in.pixbit.hijricalendar")
                            savedata?.set(dict, forKey: "sharedDocument")
                            savedata?.synchronize()
                        //loading swiftui view
                            let swiftuiView = NavigationView{PropertyListView()}
                            let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftuiView)
                            let newView = vc
                            self.view.window?.rootViewController = newView
                            self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `completeRequest(returningItems:completionHandler:)` on the `extensionContext` of your view controller.

Here is a code snippet from one of my apps:

```
  override func didSelectPost() {
    let artifact = Artifact(title: self.contentText,
                            author: self.metaAuthor,
                            url: url?.absoluteString ?? metaUrl ?? "",
                            imageUrl: metaImage,
                            siteName: self.siteName,
                            dateAdded: Date(),
                            excerpt: metaDescription,
                            notes: "",
                            tags: nil)
    self.artifactRepository?.addArtifact(artifact)
    
    self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)
  }
```

Comment: I tried this, not working in my case . After getting data in didSelectPost() may app is navigating to another 3 views as given in question.  I need to close the share extension after completing data upload in last view